# 'str' object has no attribute 'GET' when requesting to django script

Tags: python, django, request

i have been working with django to make an interactive web page. But when i try to make a Http request to a django view. It throws that error, even though i have the exact same code above and that works just fine. Here is my Python code:

```
  def test(request):
    default = {"Error" : "Could not make request"}
    name = request.GET.get('showname')
    token = getToken()
    showJs = searchShowId(name, token)
    if showJs.get('Error'):
        try: 
            token = refreshToken(token)
            showJs = searchShowId(name, token)
            return JsonResponse(showJs)
        except KeyError as error:
            token = login()
            showJs = searchShowId(name, token)
            return JsonResponse(showJs)
    else:
         return JsonResponse(showJs)

def image(request):
   default = {"Error" : "Could not make request"}
   id = request.GET.get('id')
   return JsonResponse(image(id))
```

this is the full error:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "E:\Documentos\Programming\DjangoProjects\mediaD\mediaDe\views.py" in image
  33.    return JsonResponse(image(id))

File "E:\Documentos\Programming\DjangoProjects\mediaD\mediaDe\views.py" in image
  32.    id = request.GET.get('id')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /image/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'GET'
```

Javascript Code:

```
 function search() {
      console.log('Function Called')
      var showName = document.getElementById('showName');
      console.log(showName.value);
      var name = stringToPost(showName.value);
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/request/",
        data: {
           showname: showName.value
        },
        success: function (dato) {
          dato = dato['data'];
          for (var i = 0; i < dato.length; i++) {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/image/",
                  data: {
                      id : dato[i]['id']
                  },
                  success: function (datax) {
                     console.log(datax);
                  },
              });

          }
      },
    });
```

Like i already said, the test function works perfectly, but the image one doesnt. What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in your `image` function, you `return image(id)` which calls the same function, but this time with `id` instead of a `request` object.

Try naming the 2 things differently, e.g. you can rename the view function to `image_view`.

Comment: yes! that was it. I had another function (the one that made the request to the API) and it had exactly the same name, Thank you so much